# How can i make a scrollbar start on the right and not the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done this with the css `direction: rtl;` but then some text is displayed right to left, which isn't what I want.

Is there a way to make `direction: rtl;` not modify the text and only the scrollbar or how would I make the scrollbar have the same behavior as `direction: rtl;` without displaying the text right to left?

I can use jQuery and I am open to using another library if it's truly necessary.

Comment: Where are you using that? In a `div`? What other styles are at play?

Comment: Im not sure I get exactly what you are doing, but I think you can set the scrollbar for a div, and then after align the text in an inner div inside the div your drive with the scrollbar, but have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by stating you should NOT do this, but if you can't resist you can always do:

**HTML**

`<body>
  <div class="inner">
    Your content here
  </div>
</body>`

**CSS**

`body { direction: rtl; }
.inner { direction: ltr; }`

What I think you SHOULD do is build whatever application you're working on in a way a browser understands. If you want the scrollbar direction to be opposite, than build your site like that. If you don't have to support legacy browsers, you probably can build such a thing easily with `flexbox` and `flex-direction: row-reverse`.